# SQL Soccer Points Table Last 5 Matches

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a MSSQL query for point table of all matches of this season.

The database consists of one table and table column name is;

```
Div (League name), Date, HomeTeam, AwayTeam, FTHG(FullTimeHomeGoal), FTAG (FullTimeAwayGoal)...
```

Table structure

```
Div (nvarchar)
Date (datetime)
Hometeam (nvarchar)
Awayteam (nvarchar)
Fthg (float)
Fthg (float)
```

How can i do points table of last 5 matches/games ?

```
select 
    team, 
    count(*) MP, 
    count(case when fthg > ftag then 1 end) W, 
    count(case when fthg = ftag then 1 end) D, 
    count(case when fthg < ftag then 1 end) L,
    sum(fthg) GF,
    sum(ftag) GA,
    sum(fthg) - sum(ftag) GD,
    sum(case when fthg > ftag then 3 else 0 end + case when fthg = ftag then 1 else 0 end) Pts
    from (
    select Div, hometeam team, fthg, ftag, hthg, htag from Matches 
      union all
    select Div, awayteam team, ftag, fthg, htag, hthg from Matches 
    ) a
    where div='E0'
group by team
order by Pts desc
```

Query results:

```
team        MP  W   D   L   GF  GA  GD  Pts
Chelsea     32  24  3   5   65  27  38  75
Tottenham   32  21  8   3   68  22  46  71
Liverpool   33  19  9   5   69  40  29  66
Man City    32  19  7   6   63  35  28  64
Man United  31  16  12  3   48  24  24  60
Arsenal     31  17  6   8   63  40  23  57
Everton     33  16  9   8   60  37  23  57
West Brom   33  12  8   13  39  42  -3  44
Watford     32  11  7   14  37  52  -15 40
Southampton 31  11  7   13  37  40  -3  40
Stoke       33  10  9   14  37  48  -11 39
Leicester   32  10  7   15  41  53  -12 37
West Ham    33  10  7   16  44  59  -15 37
Burnley     33  10  6   17  33  47  -14 36
Bournemouth 33  9   8   16  45  63  -18 35
Crystal Pa  32  10  5   17  44  52  -8  35
Hull        33  8   6   19  34  67  -33 30
Swansea     33  8   4   21  37  68  -31 28
Middlesbr   32  4   12  16  23  39  -16 24
Sunderland  32  5   6   21  26  58  -32 21
```

Sample data :

```
div date                    hometeam        awayteam    fthg    ftag
E0  2017-04-17 00:00:00.000 Middlesbrough   Arsenal     1       2
E0  2017-04-16 00:00:00.000 Man United      Chelsea     2       0
E0  2017-04-16 00:00:00.000 West Brom       Liverpool   0       1
E0  2017-04-15 00:00:00.000 Crystal Palace  Leicester   2       2
E0  2017-04-15 00:00:00.000 Everton         Burnley     3       1
.....
...
```

Comment: Aren't there any datetime columns?

Comment: Did you try Top 5 Date?

Comment: @mehtat_90 The date field is not distinctive for exam.
I think it's more correct to calculate teams match numbers

Comment: What you need to do is provide us with some details about your data. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @SeanLange Edited question for about data. Is it enough ?

Comment: Your table suffers with poor datatypes and a lack of normalization but what do you expect the output to be based on the sample data you have provided? Looks like the sample data is pretty sparse since you are wanting the last 5 matches. The sample provided does not even have a match for all the team that currently play in first division. I think though that you are trying to create a standings tables based only on the last 5 matches?

Comment: How do you want to handle things like last 5 not being totally consistent. Say Arsenal played 5 matches after last playing Sunderland but that would be 6 games back for Sunderland.

Comment: @SeanLange You are wrong...This exam only a part of these data.Maybe this can help you... for detail about data http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1617/all-euro-data-2016-2017.zip

Comment: Just because you have a zip file with a bunch of data does not mean it is properly normalized. On the contrary it was probably intentionally denormalized to provide in this format. Despite that can you help explain what you want here. How do you define the "last 5 matches" if the teams have not all played the same number of matches? Let's take your spreadsheet. What should the results be?

Comment: Sorry...I think, I gave the missing information.I want get result for each team of last 5 (or 6 - 8 - 15 not important) match
and according to this a points table.

Comment: @VDK Yes there is. Edited question for table structure and sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my edit to Jeremy Real's answer was rejected, I'm posting my own, with credit to @JeremyReal (also upvoted).

```
with table_a as (
    select Div, date, hometeam team, fthg, ftag, hthg, htag from Matches 
      union all
    select Div, date, awayteam team, ftag, fthg, htag, hthg from Matches 
    ) 
,table_b as (
select * from (
    select a.*
    ,row_number() over (partition by a.Div, a.team order by a.date desc) as row_num
    from table_a a) x
where row_num <= 5)

select 
    Div,
    team, 
    count(*) MP, 
    count(case when fthg > ftag then 1 end) W, 
    count(case when fthg = ftag then 1 end) D, 
    count(case when fthg < ftag then 1 end) L,
    sum(fthg) GF,
    sum(ftag) GA,
    sum(fthg) - sum(ftag) GD,
    sum(case when fthg > ftag then 3 else 0 end + case when fthg = ftag then 1 else 0 end) Pts
    from table_b
    where div='E0' --remove this line to show all divisions.
group by Div, team
order by Div, Pts desc
```

Compared with Jeremy's answer, this adds an alias (`x`) to the subquery for the `table_b` CTE. It also adds `Div` to the partitioning in that subquery and to the `group by` in main query.

My thought with including `Div` in the main query is that there *could* be teams with the same name operating in different competitions. Or even that the original data might include "cup" competitions alongside league events, and that the two should not be muddled. Depending on your data structures, you could even have multiple seasons of data in your table, which would also need to be handled.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work.

```
with table_a as (
    select Div, date, hometeam team, fthg, ftag, hthg, htag from Matches 
      union all
    select Div, date, awayteam team, ftag, fthg, htag, hthg from Matches 
    ) 
,table_b as (
select * from (
    select a.*
    ,row_number() over (partition by a.team order by a.date desc) as row_num
    from table_a a)
where row_num <= 5)

select 
    team, 
    count(*) MP, 
    count(case when fthg > ftag then 1 end) W, 
    count(case when fthg = ftag then 1 end) D, 
    count(case when fthg < ftag then 1 end) L,
    sum(fthg) GF,
    sum(ftag) GA,
    sum(fthg) - sum(ftag) GD,
    sum(case when fthg > ftag then 3 else 0 end + case when fthg = ftag then 1 else 0 end) Pts
    from table_b
    where div='E0'
group by team
order by Pts desc
```

Comment: Thank you but only match_id is not exist on table

Comment: @RobinVlaar Okay, removed it. It's not needed, but initially thought it would be required. Should work now.

Comment: Okay, partitioning by team now and eliminate extra subquery. Try this.

Comment: @RobinVlaar Also, what is the datatype of the date field? If it is a string or a number it will be necessary to cast it as a date in order for the row_number function to sort correctly.

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.

Comment: Edited question for table structure

Comment: @RobinVlaar That error message indicates possibly a formatting error of some kind, but I don't see anything wrong with the syntax. Perhaps you could try renaming the variable row_num to something else. I'm certain that using the row_number function with partition on team and order by date is the way to get the result you want, but I don't know what the syntax problem might be here. I'm not experienced with sql server and it seems like it may be particular to that system. Good luck!

Comment: Ive submitted an edit, which i think will fix the error in this. Think the definition of the table_b cte needs an alias for the subquery, like this: `from table_a a) x where row_num <= 5)`, with `x` being the alias. It doesn't matter what alias you use as long as there is one.

Comment: @SteveLovell It's worked your fix. Thank you so much.

Comment: @SteveLovell Is there another method for my question? Because when this query is running for all league, Some teams have a match count of 3 while others are 5 or 6... why ? I guess that's from the date criteria.

Comment: Depending on how "live" your data is, is it possible that you may have fewer than 5 matches for some teams? As for 6, that's more puzzling, I'll do some research.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is some potentially odd behaviour resulting from not including the `div` field in the `partition` and the final `select` (where if added you'd also need to include it in your `group by`).

Comment: @SteveLovell Okay..I fixed it. No problem. I made a mistake in some lines Thank you again